# Cannot add content using default content types

Tags: nodes, debugging

I have Article and Basic Page, but when I try to add either of these to my Drupal Site I get the following error message.

> You have not created any content types yet. Go to the content type creation page to add a new content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Structure > Menus > Navigation, goto "list links" of Navigation menu, you'll see that all of your content types are disabled except for the actual "Add content" link. Just check the enabled box and save, then you should be good to go.
[image]